# How do I redirect a subdomain to a subdirectory in primary domain serving as reverse-proxy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, heroku, dns, reverse-proxy

I'll describe the current setup first followed by what I'd like to change it to.

**Current Setup**

- Primary domain [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) pointing to a Ruby on Rails app deployed on Heroku.
- Wordpress blog blog.example.com running on [Flywheel](https://getflywheel.com/).
- RoR application serves as reverse-proxy to load Flywheel content under /blog subdirectory. For ex. [www.example.com/blog/page1](http://www.example.com/blog/page1) loads content from blog.spacebox.com/page1. We're using https://github.com/waterlink/rack-reverse-proxy for making this work.

All of the above works as expected.

**What We Want**

Now the marketing team, wanting to up the SEO game, wants blog.example.com/* to redirect to [www.example.com/blog/](http://www.example.com/blog/)*

**What I've Tried So Far (with failure, of course)**

- Setup a Redirect on Flywheel dashboard to [www.example.com/blog/$1](http://www.example.com/blog/$1) (expectedly resulted in infinite redirects).
- Deleted A record from DNSSimple for blog.example.com (pointing to Flywheel IP address), and replaced with a CNAME to point to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) (didn't work).

With the above given stack, how can the desired result be achieved? What you recommend a stack change to achieve the outcome?

Much thanks in advance, as I've spent a good few days trying to make this work.

Comment: On your actual setup, is the WordPress blog.example.com accessible from the internet? So if WordPress is accessible from the internet, does it serve the same content as example.com/blog?
In your next setup: the WordPress will be a classic Wordpress installed on a subdomain. Can't you just handle the example.com/blog to blog.ex.com redirect from Rails?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you actually want a redirect, this is actually pretty simple and can be handled in Rails routes.

```rb
get '/:blog_page', to: redirect('/blog/%{blog_page}'), constraints: { subdomain: 'blog' }
```

Every get request that comes to the blog subdomain matches this route and will be redirected to the corresponding `/blog` path.

Check the [Rails routing documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#redirection) for more details.

Comment: Thank you so much, Siim. Let me try this and come back with appropriate response ;)

Answer (score 0):

As it is more from the SEO POV and not from the Rails implementation POV, There are few options which you can give it a try -

1. As the blog app is hosted on some other server, the only thing you can do is to redirect using a SEO Friendly link pointing to that outside page.Take a look here to know [best way to make an anchor tag SEO Friendly](https://moz.com/learn/seo/anchor-text).
2. Backlinks to the rescue -  if you want more control, i would rather suggest you to make your page more SEO FRIENDLY for both Rails(who is having a link to your blog page) and also a backlink(pointing from your blog to the rails app). [You can read more here about the backlinks](https://www.semrush.com/blog/how-to-get-backlinks/).

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps I had to done to achieve similar scenario. Maybe some of them will prove helpful.

I'm not sure about the redirection step so I will only contribute a naive scenario which could be done in two ways:

1. within DNS zone create a pointer from `blog.example.com` to `example.com/blog` or
2. create simple `index.html` file within `blog.exmaple.com` directory using redirection meta tag like so

```
...
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=https://www.example.com/blog">
...
```

For my needs I also have a reverse proxy but it's been configured under nginx web server like so:

```
server {
  listen 443
  location /blog {
    root /blog/public;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
  }
}
```

with the Rails application being served by the standalone Passenger app server on port 8080.

Next, reconfigure Rails application (tested under version 6.1) to be served from subdirectory:

1. create environment variable `RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT=/blog`
2. update `config.ru` file which can use previously set variable or just hardcode it

```rb
require_relative "config/environment"

map ENV["RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT"] || "/" do
  run Rails.application
  Rails.application.load_server
end
```

3. update `config/application.rb` file by adding following entry

```
...
config.relative_url_root = ENV["RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT"] if ENV["RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT"]
...
```

Note: for above approach ensure that `ENV["RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT"]` variable is seen from the Rails console perspective.

As I stated, this is not a 1 to 1 situation with an obvious answer but it has some similarities (serving Rails app from the subdirectory) so I think it might prove useful.

Answer (score -3):

To redirect a subdomain to a subdirectory in a primary domain serving as a reverse-proxy, you can use the following steps:

1.Configure your DNS records. You will need to create a CNAME record for your subdomain that points to the IP address of your primary domain. Configure your reverse proxy. You will need to configure your reverse proxy to forward requests to your subdomain to the subdirectory in your primary domain. For example, if your subdomain is blog.example.com and you want to redirect it to the /blog subdirectory of your primary domain, then you would configure your reverse proxy to forward requests to blog.example.com to example.com/blog.

2.Configure a redirect in your primary domain. You will need to configure a redirect in your primary domain to redirect all requests to the subdomain to the subdirectory. For example, if your primary domain is example.com and you want to redirect all requests to blog.example.com to the /blog subdirectory, then you would configure a redirect in example.com to redirect all requests to /blog.

Once you have configured your DNS records, your reverse proxy, and your redirect, then all requests to your subdomain will be redirected to the subdirectory in your primary domain.

Comment: Are you aware of our [policy forbidding AI-generated answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831/354577)